# for each loop in controller adding data to object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

This is loop inside my controller:

```
 foreach(Classes::all() as $classes){
        $classes->student;
    }
    return view('configuration.configuration')->with('classes', $classes);
```

My question is how to make an object that will fill itself in each passing, so that I can pass that object to view.

Comment: `$classes->student;` has no effet, what are you trying to do exaclty?

Comment: You want to load the `student` with the each `$classe` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eager load the students of class, with no need to pars all classes over a loop, you can do :

```
$classes = Classes::with('students')->all();
```

Assuming that you have a  "one-to-many" relationship like this in your `Classes` model:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Student');
}
```

Comment: thank you... I'm still wraping my head around eager loading and eloquent